# How to insert an image when tapping the screen in android?

Tags: java, android

I need to create a Tic Tac Toe application using Java. When the player taps the screen, the game must insert the images of X and O. Both pngs are stored in the drawable folder. But the application doesn't seem to work. When I press the screen, nothing happens, and I couldn't find any error in the Logcat panel except: Unable to match the desired swap behavior. Also, the app must open in a new Intent() when pressing the Play button.

This is the code below for **Game**.

```
package com.example.tictactoe;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat;
    public class Game extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
    private TextView playerOneScore, playerTwoScore, playerStatus;
    private Button[] buttons = new Button[9];
    private Button reset, playagain;
    private int playerOneScoreCount, playerTwoScoreCount, rounds;
    boolean playerOneActive;
    int[] gameState = {2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2};
    int[][] winningPositions = {{0, 1, 2}, {3, 4, 5}, {6, 7, 8}, {0, 3, 6}, {1, 4, 7}, {2, 5, 8}, {0, 4, 8}, {2, 4, 6}};
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_game);
        playerOneScore = findViewById(R.id.score_Player1);
        playerTwoScore = findViewById(R.id.score_Player2);
        playerStatus = findViewById(R.id.textStatus);
        reset = findViewById(R.id.btn_about_game);
        buttons[0] = findViewById(R.id.btn0);
        buttons[1] = findViewById(R.id.btn1);
        buttons[2] = findViewById(R.id.btn2);
        buttons[3] = findViewById(R.id.btn3);
        buttons[4] = findViewById(R.id.btn4);
        buttons[5] = findViewById(R.id.btn5);
        buttons[6] = findViewById(R.id.btn6);
        buttons[7] = findViewById(R.id.btn7);
        buttons[8] = findViewById(R.id.btn8);
        playerOneScoreCount = 0;
        playerTwoScoreCount = 0;
        playerOneActive = true;
        rounds = 0;
    }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if (!((Button) view).getText().toString().equals("")) {
            return;
        }
        String buttonID = view.getResources().getResourceEntryName(view.getId());
        int gameStatePointer = Integer.parseInt(buttonID.substring(buttonID.length() - 1));
        if (playerOneActive) {
            // ((Button) view).setText("X");
            view.setOnContextClickListener((View.OnContextClickListener) ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.x_sign));
            gameState[gameStatePointer] = 0;
        } else {
            // ((Button) view).setText("O");
            view.setOnContextClickListener((View.OnContextClickListener) ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.o_sign));
            gameState[gameStatePointer] = 1;
        }
        rounds++;
    }
    public boolean checkWinner() {
        boolean winnerResults = false;
        for (int[] winningPositions : winningPositions) {
            if (gameState[winningPositions[0]] == gameState[winningPositions[1]] && gameState[winningPositions[1]] == gameState[winningPositions[2]] && gameState[winningPositions[0]] != 2) {
                winnerResults = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        return winnerResults;
    }
    private void updatePlayerScore() {
        playerOneScore.setText(Integer.toString(playerOneScoreCount));
        playerTwoScore.setText(Integer.toString(playerTwoScoreCount));
    }
    private void playAgain() {
        rounds = 0;
        playerOneActive = true;
        for (int i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
            gameState[i] = 2;
            buttons[i].setText("");
        }
        playerStatus.setText("Status");
    }
}
```

**MainActivity**

````
 package com.example.tictactoe;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Tic Tac Toe");
    }
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this,Game.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```
````

**activity_game**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:background="@color/black"
    tools:context=".Game">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/texttitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="Welcome to Tic Tac Toe!"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="25sp"/>
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relative_layout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/texttitle"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_player1"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Player 1 Score"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="26sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_player2"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@id/text_player1"
            android:text="Player 2 Score"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="26sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/score_Player1"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/text_player1"
            android:text="0"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="26sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/score_Player2"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/text_player2"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@id/score_Player1"
            android:text="0"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="26sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </RelativeLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout_linear"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/relative_layout"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn0"
                android:layout_width="75dp"
                android:layout_height="75dp"
                android:layout_marginHorizontal="5dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="1.25dp"
                android:backgroundTint="@color/black"
                android:textColorLink="#F8F6F6"
                android:textSize="26sp"
                android:drawableEnd="@drawable/xo_48x48"
                android:clickable="true"/>
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn1"
                android:layout_width="75dp"
                android:layout_height="75dp"
                android:layout_marginHorizontal="5dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="1.25dp"
                android:backgroundTint="@color/black"
                android:textSize="26sp"
                android:drawableRight="@drawable/xo_48x48"
                android:clickable="true"/>
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn2"
                android:layout_width="75dp"
                android:layout_height="75dp"
                android:layout_marginHorizontal="5dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="1.25dp"
                android:backgroundTint="@color/black"
                android:textSize="26sp"
                android:drawableEnd="@drawable/xo_48x48"
                android:clickable="true"/>
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn3"
                android:layout_width="75dp"
                android:layout_height="75dp"
                android:layout_marginHorizontal="5dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="1.25dp"
                android:backgroundTint="@color/black"
                android:textSize="26dp"
                android:drawableRight="@drawable/xo_48x48"
                android:clickable="true"/>
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn4"
                android:layout_width="75dp"
                android:layout_height="75dp"
                android:layout_marginHorizontal="5dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="1.25dp"
                android:backgroundTint="@color/black"
                android:textSize="26dp"
                android:drawableRight="@drawable/xo_48x48"
                android:clickable="true"/>
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn5"
                android:layout_width="75dp"
                android:layout_height="75dp"
                android:layout_marginHorizontal="5dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="1.25dp"
                android:backgroundTint="@color/black"
                android:textSize="26sp"
                android:drawableEnd="@drawable/xo_48x48"
                android:clickable="true"/>
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn6"
                android:layout_width="75dp"
                android:layout_height="75dp"
                android:layout_marginHorizontal="5dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="1.25dp"
                android:backgroundTint="@color/black"
                android:textSize="26sp"
                android:drawableEnd="@drawable/xo_48x48"
                android:clickable="true"/>
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn7"
                android:layout_width="75dp"
                android:layout_height="75dp"
                android:layout_marginHorizontal="5dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="1.25dp"
                android:backgroundTint="@color/black"
                android:textSize="26sp"
                android:drawableEnd="@drawable/xo_48x48"
                android:clickable="true"/>
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn8"
                android:layout_width="75dp"
                android:layout_height="75dp"
                android:layout_marginHorizontal="5dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="1.25dp"
                android:backgroundTint="@color/black"
                android:textSize="26sp"
                android:drawableEnd="@drawable/xo_48x48"
                android:clickable="true"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textStatus"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/layout_linear"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:text="Status"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="26sp" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_play_game"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/textStatus"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:backgroundTint="#651FFF"
        android:text="Play Again"
        android:textSize="26sp"/>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_about_game"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/btn_play_game"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:backgroundTint="#cc1234"
        android:text="Reset Game"
        android:textSize="26sp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: at first: attach `OnClickListener` to every button (or maybe you do so in xml?)